# System Methods, variables and properties in Vb 6

Tags: vb6

I am looking for a source which can give me access to system methods, variables and properties in VB6. I am actually comparing all the variables and methods in a VB6 program and have to determine if this is a System variable or method or  a user defined entity.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the sub pages of the [VB6 language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338033%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) in MSDN. Note that there is no "System" object and the conects of the VB/VBA/OLE type libraries will be the same for all machines.
The object browser that Slaks mentioned also tell you where properties and methods are defined
.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear.
It sounds like you're looking for the Object Browser.

Comment: No,  I am not looking for Object Browser, I am looking for a place which enlists the names of System variable, methods and properties, so that I can compare at looking the system list to my list to decide if the given variable or method is user defined or exists in system form Before. Like 'Err' is a system known entity. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  You can see all of these in the Object Browser.